# Using addFile with pipe on a yarn cluster

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I've been using pyspark with my YARN cluster with success.  The work I'm
doing involves using the RDD's pipe command to send data through a binary
I've made.  I can do this easily in pyspark like so (assuming 'sc' is
already defined):

```
sc.addFile("./dumb_prog") 
t= sc.parallelize(range(10))
t.pipe("dumb_prog")
t.take(10) # Gives expected result
```

However, if I do the same thing in Scala, the pipe command gets a 'Cannot
run program "dumb_prog": error=2, No such file or directory' error.  Here's
the code in the Scala shell:

```
sc.addFile("./dumb_prog")
val t = sc.parallelize(0 until 10)
val u = t.pipe("dumb_prog")
u.take(10)
```

Why does this only work in Python and not in Scala?  Is there a way I can
get it to work in Scala?

Here is the full error message from the scala side:

```
[59/3965]
14/09/29 13:07:47 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: take at <console>:17
14/09/29 13:07:47 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 3 (take at <console>:17) with 1
output partitions (allowLocal=true)
14/09/29 13:07:47 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: Stage 3(take at
<console>:17)
14/09/29 13:07:47 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
14/09/29 13:07:47 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
14/09/29 13:07:47 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting Stage 3 (PipedRDD[3] at pipe
at <console>:14), which has no missing parents
14/09/29 13:07:47 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(2136) called with
curMem=7453, maxMem=278302556
14/09/29 13:07:47 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_3 stored as values in
memory (estimated size 2.1 KB, free 265.4 MB)
14/09/29 13:07:47 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(1389) called with
curMem=9589, maxMem=278302556
14/09/29 13:07:47 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_3_piece0 stored as bytes
in memory (estimated size 1389.0 B, free 265.4 MB)
14/09/29 13:07:47 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_3_piece0 in memory
on 10.10.0.20:37574 (size: 1389.0 B, free: 265.4 MB)
14/09/29 13:07:47 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Updated info of block
broadcast_3_piece0
14/09/29 13:07:47 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from Stage 3
(PipedRDD[3] at pipe at <console>:14)
14/09/29 13:07:47 INFO YarnClientClusterScheduler: Adding task set 3.0 with
1 tasks
14/09/29 13:07:47 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID
6, SERVERNAME, PROCESS_LOCAL, 1201 bytes)
14/09/29 13:07:47 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_3_piece0 in memory
on SERVERNAME:57118 (size: 1389.0 B, free: 530.3 MB)
14/09/29 13:07:47 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 6,
SERVERNAME): java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "dumb_prog": error=2,
No such file or directory
    java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1041)
    org.apache.spark.rdd.PipedRDD.compute(PipedRDD.scala:119)
    org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:262)
    org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:229)
    org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:62)
    org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:54)
```

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar issue in spark 1.3.0 in Yarn client mode. When I look in the *app cache* directory, the file never gets pushed to the executors even when using `--files`. But when I added the below, it did push to each executor:

```
sc.addFile("dumb_prog",true)
t.pipe("./dumb_prog")
```

I think it is a bug, but the above got me past the issue.

Comment: sc.add ("hdfs:///file script path in hdfs")  is not working have you tried with spark 2.2